# show multiple trends and different axis for stockChart

Tags: date, highcharts, google-maps-markers, axis, jstockchart

The chart trying to create as shown below [image]

```
the working fiddle is as shown below 
     https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xy6ftpn5/
```

how to stack the multiple markers on the same date as in the picture. Tried to add multiple series
in  series parameter

also need trying to figure out how to show multiple y-axis separately for different chart like line marker and bar chart

any pointers will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to define the `yAxis` property as an array with multiple objects and then assign each series to the proper `yAxis`. For example:

```
yAxis: [{
  ...
}, {
  ...
}, {
  ...
}],

series: [{
  ...,
  yAxis: 0
}, {
  ...,
  yAxis: 1
}, {
  ...,
  yAxis: 1
}, {
  ...,
  yAxis: 2
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/oqbzcm7y/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.yAxis

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/axes

Comment: please check the picture markers show come one above the other for that day and different series

Comment: Hi @DhanaLaxshmi, Thanks for the explanation. You need to set data for the flag series with the same `x` value as columns. Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mh05dno6/